# Search string in Listbox

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I'm having troubles finding a string into a listbox, my string NombreCompleto is made of 3 strings that I previously had read from a file(ESSD), after I had recovered this string, I want to know if this string is in my listbox3, I tried several methods but it doesnt seem to work.
Here is my code.

```
foreach (string h in Directory.EnumerateFiles(NomDirec, "resume*"))
{
   this.listBox1.Items.Add(h);
    var NombreLinea = File.ReadLines(h);
    foreach (string item in NombreLinea)
    {
        NombreAbuscar.Add(item.Remove(item.IndexOf(':')));
        this.listBox3.Items.Add(item.Remove(item.IndexOf(':')));

}

foreach (string t in Directory.EnumerateFiles(NomDirec, "ESSD1*"))
{
    string[] Nombre = File.ReadLines(t).ElementAtOrDefault(6).Split(':');
    string[] ApellidoPat = File.ReadLines(t).ElementAtOrDefault(7).Split(':');
    string[] ApellidoMat = File.ReadLines(t).ElementAtOrDefault(8).Split(':');
    string NombreCompleto = ApellidoPat[1]+" "+ ApellidoMat[1] +","+" "+ Nombre[1];
    string Nom2 = NombreCompleto.ToString();

    int index = listBox3.FindString(Nom2);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(t);
        MessageBox.Show("Find It");
    }
    else { MessageBox.Show("Not Found :@"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
                            int index = -1;
                            for (int i = 0; i < listBox3.Items.Count; ++i)
                               if (listBox3.Items[i].Text == Nom2) { index = i; break; }
                            if (index != -1)
                            {
                                this.listBox1.Items.Add(t);
                                MessageBox.Show("Find It");
                            }
                            else { MessageBox.Show("Not Found :@");
```

Comment: What is ind? where you declare it? Thanks!

Comment: @carloscarbajal Sorry. I just meant `index`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - `based on Linq operator Where, ...`

```
var selectedItems = from li in listBox3.Items
                    where li.Text == Nom2
                    select li.Text;

if(selectedItems.Any()) 
....
```

Comment: You can use `Any` rather than `Count() == 0)`.  It not only conveys the meaning much more clearly, but it will perform better too (it doesn't need to iterate the whole sequence, just try to get the first item).  You'll also want to remove the `ToList` as well, as there is no need to eagerly iterate the entire sequence into a list.

Comment: could you explain it, i´m kind  new in c# Thanks!

Comment: carlos you have initial sequence, you iterate about items of collection with  'from' - you filter with 'where' - you select your item with 'select'

Answer (score 0):

Really easy way to find if a certain string is in a listbox.

```
private void btnAddRecipe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool DoesItemExist = false;
    string searchString = txtRecipeName.Text;
    int index = lstRecipes.FindStringExact(searchString, -1);

    if (index != -1) DoesItemExist = true;
    else DoesItemExist = false;

    if (DoesItemExist)
    {
       //do something
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not found", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }

    PopulateRecipe();
}
```